# Facebook JSON Service is not retrieving more than 1000 facebook friend

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, developer-tools

I am getting issue on the following code, can anyone solve it?
Here is my code description:

```
$friends=get_data(https://graph.facebook.com/".$facbookid."/friends?access_token=".Useraccess_token);
```

Here is the get_data function and it return appropriate data:

```
function get_data($url) {
    $ch = curl_init();
    $timeout = 5;
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL,$url);
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT,$timeout);
    $data = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    return $data;
}
```

Then I used JSON SERVICE:

```
$json = new Services_JSON();
$friends = $json->decode($friends);
echo "print data".$friends->data;
if (isset($friends->data))
    {   
        foreach($friends->data as $friend) 
        {
            $i++;
            $friendList[] = $friend->id;   
        }
    }
```

Problem is that, when I have only 1000 friends , its retrieving the data. But it’s not working when the friend is more than 1000.

Infact, I have used `$friends = $json->decode($friends,true);` etc.
Can anyone help me?

Comment: What php version are you using? Native JSON decoding via `json_decode()` has been included with php since v5.2. http://us3.php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php

Answer (score 1):

Facebook's graph API limits the number of results to prevent it (or you) from suffering from poor performance or running out of memory. You need to use [the paging features that the API provides](https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/478/), i.e. the `limit`, `since` and `until` parameters.

It's best not to change the default limit unless you have good reason (not being bothered to page is not a good reason). Helpfully, all results also contain a `paging` structure telling you the URL for the next (and previous) page.